# Configurar límite de ejecución EJB timer a una hora y minuto específico

Tags: java, ejb

En un EJB timer Debo configurar en la anotacion @Schedule su límite de ejecución a una hora y minuto específico, la configuración actual que tengo es la siguiente:

```
@Schedule(second = "00", minute = "*/15", hour = "10-11", dayOfWeek = "Mon-Sun", dayOfMonth = "*", month = "*", year = "*", info = "Prueba")
private void scheduledTimeout(final Timer t) {   ...     }
```

Lo anterior indica que la ejecucion se realizará de 10 am a 11:45 am cada 15 minutos, pero lo que necesito es configurarlo para que la ultima ejecucion del dia sea a las 11:30 am exactamente. Como debo hacer la configuración?? muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solución sin alterar el Scheduled

```
@Schedule(second = "00", minute = "*/15", hour = "10-11", dayOfWeek = "Mon-Sun", dayOfMonth = "*", month = "*", year = "*", info = "Prueba")
private void scheduledTimeout(final Timer t) {  
     if(horaActual <= horaUltimaEjecucion)
          hazElTrabajo();
}
```

Si se ejecuta a las 11:30 y definimos horaUltimaEjecucion como 11:31 para asegurarnos no tener problemas con segundos, se ejecutara normal.

Pero a las 11:45, aunque se ejecute el cron, no realizamos nada.